# Bind text with selectbox (On Click) Jquery

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-ui, drag-and-drop

I create a small application to add text from textarea to div block..I want when user click on yellow div text not get append and the properties (font family, font size) of the selected text also highlight in the selectbox

```
$(document).ready( function() {
    $('#page1').click(function(e){
    var $el = $("<li class='text'>"+$('#ta').val()+"</li>"),
        $this = $(this), offset = $this.offset();
    $el.css({
        position: 'absolute',
        left: e.pageX - offset.left,
        top: e.pageY - offset.top
    });
    $this.append($el);
    ($el).draggable();
    $("#page1 li").click(function(){
    $("#page1 li").removeClass('active');
    $(this).addClass("active");

    });
});
        $("#fs").change(function() {
            $('li.active').css("font-family", $(this).val());
        });
        $("#size").change(function() {
            $('li.active').css("font-size", $(this).val() + "px");
        });

      });
```

Jsfiddle link: http://jsfiddle.net/sharma_pooja/P2Kyk/31/

Comment: so what is your problem?

Comment: Could you be a tad more specific. Are you trying to get a value or the clicked coordinates, which would be page.X etc.

Comment: What exactly is not working for you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$('#block').click(function(e){

    var $this = $(this);
    var $textBlock = $this.children('p');
    var _offset = $this.offset();

    $textBlock.css({
        position: 'relative',
        left: e.pageX - _offset.left,
        top: e.pageY - _offset.top
    });

});
```

And add CSS `overflow: hidden;` to the `#block` class. It will hide rest of text which will be overflowing the block when positioned near the block border.

---

**UPDATE**

For draggable option you should use [*jQuery UI*](http://jqueryui.com/download/) and can do smth. like this

```
$('#block p')
    .draggable() // for moving the `<p>` around with your mouse
    .disableTextSelect(); // to disable text selection inside container
```

Here is **[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/P2Kyk/12/)** for both cases: when clicking parent container and dragging the text block itself.

Comment: Thanks for the Answer! on every click it append text can u help me how to select the text and drag it anywhere??

Comment: @pooja9, I've tested it within your fiddle and it is not appending anything it just moves to proper coordinates on `click` event. And you need `drag-n-drop` option here as I understood. Am I right?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add the paragraph of text which will havee coords of the point in #block element you hit with mouse, then you'll have to do the following:

1) add position: relative to #block element css

2) change #block click event handler like so:

```
   $('#block').click(function(e){
        var $el = $("<p>"+$('#ta').val()+"</p>"),
            $this = $(this), offset = $this.offset();
        $el.css({
            position: 'absolute',
            left: e.pageX - offset.left,
            top: e.pageY - offset.top
        });
        $this.append($el);
    });
```

Comment: Thanks for the Answer!
on every click it append text can u help me how to select the text and drag it anywhere??